# Are there any suggestions for replacing specific characters in MariaDB tables, and table columns?

Tags: sql, windows, mysqli, command-line-interface, mariadb

I'm having difficulty replacing a " ".  I understand that MariaDB's SQL syntax allows for replacing characters (via string); I've already attempted to do so, but it continues giving me the same error of not recognizing the structure of the syntax.

On a side note, is anyone aware of any functions, triggers, and or modules that allow autonomous alteration of a table, as well as columns, that enable/permit/allow name changing, when the table's created?

(from comment)

```
ALTER  TABLE xover_sao MODIFY COLUMN 'Abell Object' 'xover_sao_object' VARCHAR(255);
-: 
ALTER  TABLE xover_sao MODIFY 'Abell Object' 'xover_sao_object' VARCHAR(255);
-: 
ALTER  TABLE xover_sao MODIFY 'Abell Object' REPLACE('Abell Object',
                ' ', ''
                          );
-: 
ALTER  TABLE xover_sao MODIFY 'Abell Object' REPLACE('Abell Object',
                ' ', ''
                          );
```

Comment: Are you referring to replacing " " in the values of the columns, or the actual column names?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you got? What does the code look like?

Comment: Let's see the "replace" code you tried.

Comment: @Uueerdo: I'm attempting to replace the " " with a "_" in all the column names, of all tables.

Comment: @Jacobm001: My error message is; ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near "...blah, blah, blah syntax..." - the error is continuous, no matter the structure, nor what I use for syntax.

Comment: @RickJames: I've used...
-: ALTER TABLE xover_sao MODIFY COLUMN 'Abell Object' 'xover_sao_object' VARCHAR(255);
-: ALTER TABLE xover_sao MODIFY 'Abell Object' 'xover_sao_object' VARCHAR(255);
-: ALTER TABLE xover_sao MODIFY 'Abell Object' REPLACE('Abell Object', ' ', '_');
-: ALTER TABLE xover_sao MODIFY 'Abell Object' REPLACE('Abell Object', ' ', '_');

Answer (score 0):

`MODIFY` does not allow for changing the name.

No expressions are allowed for `col_name`.

So, this is the closest to possible:

```
ALTER TABLE xover_sao
    CHANGE COLUMN 'Abell Object' 'xover_sao_object' VARCHAR(255);
```

But be sure to include any thing else in the definition, such as `NOT NULL`, `CHARACTER SET`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the syntax isn't recognized, stating that it's an error, and fails.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in syntax for doing things like replacing characters in column names, or using expressions of any type for column names, but you can use queries on `information_schema`.`columns` to generate sql scripts that effectively do.

Something like...

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `", c.table_schema, "`.`", c.table_name, "` "
              , "CHANGE COLUMN `", c.column_name, "` "
              , "`", REPLACE(c.column_name, " ", "_"), "` "
              , -- [use information from c to reconstruct the exact definition here]
              , ";") AS sqlStmt
FROM information_schema.columns AS c
WHERE c.column_name LIKE "% %"
;
```

Comment: I'll give that one a shot.  Thank you.  With that, perhaps I'll have to write my own function to do so.